# How to make a component path the root url in Angular 6

Tags: angular, routes

I have an Angular 6 application with several page routes. I want to make the home component the root url so that when the application initially serves (ng serve -o) instead of going to localhost:4200 which is essentially a blank page with a navbar, but to got to localhost:4200/home which is my home page component. I've tried:

```
{ path: '', component:HomeComponent },
```

In the app.module.ts file but it doesn't work. Any advise on how to solve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: @TDeo try this `{path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}` if doesn't work then share link of `https://stackblitz.com/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this config:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
```

Comment: @T.Doe: You are saying it doesn't redirect to "http://localhost:4200/home" when you enter "http://locahost:4200"?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm saying. I know logically this is the correct answer but I've got nothing special going on in this application for this to not be working.

Comment: @T.Doe: I am afraid, I won't be able to help unless I see your app. I tried to implement this in a new app, it works just fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-74bxyg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: @T.Doe You have added a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your app component, right?

Comment: In the app.component.html? Absolutely.